# How to produce multiple regression plane for 3d graph in plotly

Tags: r

I want to create a 3d regression plane for my graph. I'm unsure why it's not working, but I think it is to do with my use of the predict function (and the corresponding data).

```
ESS3 <- ESS2 %>%
  select(agertr, agea, eduyrs)
ESS3 <- na.omit(ESS3)

m5 <- lm(agertr ~ agea + eduyrs, data = ESS3)

# predict over sensible grid of values

ageas <- unique(ESS3$agea)
eduyrs1 <- unique(ESS3$eduyrs)
agertrs <- unique(ESS3$agertr)
grid <- with(ESS3, expand.grid(ageas, eduyrs1, agertrs))
d <- setNames(data.frame(grid), c("agea", "eduyrs", "agertrs"))


vals <- predict(model, newdata = d)

# form matrix and give to plotly
m <- matrix(vals, nrow = length(unique(d$agea)), ncol = length(unique(d$eduyrs)))

p <- plot_ly(m5, x = ~agea, y = ~agertr, z = ~eduyrs)
layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title = 'Age'),
                    yaxis = list(title = 'Age of Retirement'),
                    zaxis = list(title = 'Years of Education')))

p %>% add_surface(x = ~ageas, y = ~eduyrs1, z = ~m)
```

The two errors produced are:

> Error in predict(model, newdata = d) : object 'model' not found Error
>   in matrix(vals, nrow = length(unique(d$agea)), ncol =
>   length(unique(d$eduyrs))) :    object 'vals' not found

This code is a bit beyond my ability so sorry if my code is a bit all over the place. Thanks for any help and advice.

Comment: `vals <- predict(model, newdata = d)` the problem here seems to be that your model is called `m5` not model: `m5 <- lm(agertr ~ agea + eduyrs, data = ESS3)`

Comment: Thanks, that has worked but now having some trouble visualising the graph. It currently has the scatterplot and then a number of planes visualised above the graph. the error messages it throws are:

Error: First argument, `data`, must be a data frame or shared data.
I assume my plot_ly() call should have ESS3, not m5? 

and:

Error in UseMethod("layout") : 
  no applicable method for 'layout' applied to an object of class "list".  
Any ideas how to make it so my only plane is the regression plane? Thanks again.

Comment: `p <- plot_ly(m5, x = ~agea, y = ~agertr, z = ~eduyrs) %>%
layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title = 'Age'),
                    yaxis = list(title = 'Age of Retirement'),
                    zaxis = list(title = 'Years of Education')))`

Comment: It's still showing each point as a plane.